# jQuery image changer interferes with dropdown nav?

Tags: jquery, css

Nav gets pushed behind the image changer. I've tried overflow:hidden on a few divs but it didn't fix. I've been reading and z-index has worked for other similar issues but not sure where to implement. Any ideas? Thanks!

http://burnslawpa.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your current style sheet add the following:

```
#navbar li ul {
  position:relative;
  z-index:999999;
}
```

Note: `z-index` can only be used on `positioned` elements. Hence the `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

z-index works on positioned elements.

Try to add this to your #navbar

```
z-index: 10000;
position: relative;
```